# How to derive the Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, differentiation

I'm having trouble differentiating the following when making a change of co-ordinates to determine the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric).

$$r'^{2}=r^{2}C(r)$$

Then taking the total derivative of both sides, the answer says;

$$dr^{2}=\frac{4r'^{2}dr'^{2}}{2C(r)r+r^{2}C'(r)}$$

I cannot seem to get this answer??

Comment: See lecture 4 of the PSI gravitational physics course, the derivation is done with the Cartan formalism using differential forms.

Comment: I need it derived this way as this is what my exams uses

Comment: Have you looked here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriving_the_Schwarzschild_solution

Comment: @user32462 If the question on the exam is 'Derive the Schwarzschild metric', I'm pretty sure you can do it in any (correct) way you prefer. Physics isn't about literal reproduction. I believe there's also a derivation in chapter 5 of Sean Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry*.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): The denominator in the last formula should be squared.

Answer (score 2):

The change of variables provided is given by,

$$r'^2 = r^2C(r)$$

Taking a derivative of $r'$ with respect to $r$ yields,

$$\frac{dr'}{dr} = \frac{d}{dr}\left( r\sqrt{C(r)}\right) = \sqrt{C(r)}+ \frac{rC'(r)}{2\sqrt{C(r)}}$$

by applying the product and chain rule. We now have an expression which relates $dr$ to $dr'$, namely,

$$dr' = \left[ \sqrt{C(r)}+ \frac{rC'(r)}{2\sqrt{C(r)}}\right] dr$$

Squaring both sides yields the correct expression,

$$dr^2= \left( C(r)+\frac{r^2 C'(r)^2}{4C(r)}+rC'(r)\right)^{-1}dr'^2$$

Alternative, we can express this relation in terms of $r'$ with the substitution $r=r'/\sqrt{C(r)}$.